# Using lapply to perform custom-defined function of element comparisons

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I'm trying to look for a more R way of applying my function that compares two strings together to named list elements within named list. Looking for a way to go about doing this without for loops, so I've taken a look at `lapply`; any advice I'd greatly appreciate!

Here is a reproducible example:

```
my_list <- list(coca = c(13, 422, 131, 2), cola = c(11, 53, 3))
names(my_list$coca) <- c("sprite", "coke", "pepsi", "cocacoca")
names(my_list$cola) <- c("lemonade", "juice", "colacola")

compare_substr <- function(word1, word2, min_char){

 # INPUT: word1, word2, and min_char (optional)
 # OUTPUT: TRUE or FALSE

 if(class(word1) != "character" || class(word2) != "character"){
   stop("Error: Words being compared are not in character format")
 }
 if(missing(min_char)){
   min_char <- nchar(word1)
 }
 if(substring(word1, 1, min_char) == substring(word2, 1, min_char)){
   return(TRUE)
 }
 else{
   return(FALSE)
 }
}
```

The end result should look like this so I can filter on the ones that says `TRUE`

```
$coca
sprite     coke    pepsi cocacoca 
FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE 

$cola
lemonade    juice colacola 
FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
```

My approach currently is to go through a for loop, but I know there is a much cleaner way to doing so with lapply, but I'm beginning to think that my `compare_substr` function has to be changed to do so... Is there a way to accomplish this without changing the function?

Comment: What is the expected output ? Please add that.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the expected output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:** This is using `sapply` function:

**Explanation:**

1 - For each name in the `my_list`, `grepl` function checks if the name is present in sublist names or not. `grepl` returns a boolean. 
2 - We save the output of previous step in our new `plist`. 
3 - Finally, we set the names.

```
# create a new list
library(stringr)
plist <- list()

# match names and update the new list
plist <- sapply(names(my_list), function(x) {

    plist[[x]] <- grepl(x, names(my_list[[x]]))


}) 

# set names
names(plist$coca) <- c("sprite", "coke", "pepsi", "cocacoca")
names(plist$cola) <- c("lemonade", "juice", "colacola")

# output
    $coca
  sprite     coke    pepsi cocacoca 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE 

$cola
lemonade    juice colacola 
   FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
```

**Method 2:** Also, You can do like this using for loop (good to know) :

```
library(stringr)
new_list <- list()
for(i in names(my_list))
{

    # get name of the sublist
    temp <- names(my_list[[i]])

    # check if the name of parent list is present (this returns boolean)
    sol <- str_detect(temp, i)

    # update new list
    new_list[[i]] <- sol
    names(new_list[[i]]) <- temp

}

print(new_list)

$coca
  sprite     coke    pepsi cocacoca 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE 

$cola
lemonade    juice colacola 
   FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Is there any way to do this with one of the apply families?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do with lapply. I'll add it too.

Comment: I've added the apply solution. Please check.

Comment: This works perfectly! Can you briefly explain what is going on with the sapply and how it is being used with grepl to do the comparisons?